# How to find, replace and break String containing xml into array?

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, split

Let's say I have something like:

```
Sample 1: Your number is <foo>12345</foo> and your code is <foo>29939</foo>. 
Sample 2: Your number is <foo attr="x">12345</foo> and your code is <foo>29939</foo>.
```

I would like to break this String into an array of string.

Something like the following for Sample 1:

```
array[0] = Your number is
array[1] = 12345
array[2] = and your code is
array[3] = 29939
```

Sample 2:

```
array[0] = Your number is
array[1] = x|12345 (adding attr value to it)
array[2] = and your code is
array[3] = 29939
```

I am looking for `<foo>` with or without attribute in the String and need to break the String accordingly.

I found an easy way to replace something under  with some value.

Example: `matcher.replaceAll("bar")` which resulted in something like:

```
Your number is bar and your code is bar
```

What I would like to see is to the break the string into an array or list whenever I see the tag `<foo>` in the string value.

Comment: String.split is what you need

Comment: Are nested tags possible? Like `abc <foo>def<bar>123</bar>xyz</foo>`? If so how should they be handled?

Comment: @JunedAhsan I don't think so. OP needs something more like parsing the contents of this half xml string.

Comment: best to use an xml parser. if you did not have the need to get attribute values form within the tags then you could have easily done string.split("<foo>|</foo>")

Comment: No tested tags... I am only looking for something that is <foo> and <foo> may have a single attribute, let's call it "attr" and also <foo> is case insensitive as I'm getting XML in the middle of a regular string... I found ways to get it case insensitive etc.,

Comment: You may try wrapping the current string with `<bar></bar>` and use an XML parser.

Comment: In general, you will not be successful trying to parse arbitrary xml or html using a regex.  You can succeed if you have a limited, well-defined set of cases to recognize.  See [the canonical answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/17300)

Comment: The problem is that the string is not pure XML. If it were, then I wouldn't use regex for it... I rather use XML parsing technologies to parse it... What I'm trying to do is that when I see <foo> I need to process those string values differently. And the <foo> tag may have the attribute too though it is optional...

Comment: I had something like:  String FOO_TAG_PATTERN = "(?i)<foo([^>]*)>(.+?)</foo>";
 String FOO_TAG_ATTR =  "\\s*(?i) attr\\s*=\\s*(\"([^\"]*\")|'[^']*'|([^'\">\\s]+))";

Comment: You can make it "pure" XML by wrapping it in an arbitrary root level tag, if it is an otherwise well-formed fragment... I've had success before by taking the "sample" text and wrapping a tag around it — `sample text` becomes `<wrap>sample text</wrap>` then parse it with an XML parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that format of your text doesn't have any nested tags you should be fine with something like:

```
String[] arr = sentence
        .trim()
        .replaceAll("<foo\\s+attr=\"([^\"]+)\">", "<foo>$1|")
        .replaceAll("^<foo>|</foo>\\.?$","")
        .split("\\s?</?foo>\\s?");
```

which will:

1. `trim()` trim whitespaces at start and end of your text
2. `replaceAll("<foo\\s+attr=\"([^\"]+)\">", "<foo>$1|")` replace each `<foo attr="data">` with `<foo>data|` which means it changes

   ```
   Your number is <foo attr=\"x\">12345</foo> and your code is <foo>29939</foo>.
   ```

   into

   ```
   Your number is <foo>x|12345</foo> and your code is <foo>29939</foo>.
   //                  ^^^^^^^
   ```

   so now we have only `<foo>` and `</foo>` so we can simply split our string on these tags
3. `replaceAll("^<foo>|</foo>\\.?$","")` now to prepare for split on `<foo>` or `</foo>` we need to remove the ones at start and end of the string to avoid having empty elements in result array
4. `split("\\s?</?foo>\\s?");` split on `<foo>` or `</foo>` (including optional whitespaces surrounding them.